# how to add parameters dynamically on clicktag on adwords

Tags: dynamic, flash, google-ads-api

I'm trying to add a dynamically tracking parameter at the moment when the user clicks on flash banners vehiculated via AdWords.

My criative has two click areas and I want to be able to detect which one was clicked.

But as far I know, Google does not explain clearly how to do that, if possible.